# No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’

Tags: haskell, geometry, sqrt

One more question on SO with the same title. I've read already answered questions here but still I don't understand how can I solve these

```
No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
In the expression: (a + b + c) / 2
-- and
No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
In the first argument of ‘(>)’, namely
```

in this simple function that is for finding the area of a triangle by 3 sides.

```
----- Heron's formula -----
-- S = sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)), where p = (a+b+c)/2

isTriangle :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
isTriangle a b c = let p = (a + b + c) / 2
                   in if (sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)) > 0)
                      then True
                      else False
```

Any help and explanation of what is wrong here is appreciated.

---

**update:**
In the way of [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) i've got working (seems to be so) solution. But the issue with *"No instance for"* is still unresolved for me. I do want to figure it out.

```
-- works fine
import Data.List (sort)
isTriangle :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
isTriangle a b c = let sides = sort[a, b, c]
                   in if ((last sides) < head sides + (head $ tail sides))
                      then True
                      else False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sqrt` function has type

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

(it's actually a method of the `Floating` class) so it works for any standard floating point-based numerical representation, including `Double`, `Complex Double`, and other, less important, types. It likely also works for non-standard, non-floating-point, very fancy numerical representation. But `Int` does not support square roots, because only perfect squares have integral square roots. You should probably switch to a type that offers them. If you need to start from `Int` values, you can convert them with

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral i, Num n) => i -> n
```

---

For your particular purpose (figuring out if you have a triangle at all), you don't actually need to calculate the square root. Can you see why?

Comment: Very, very good explanation! And no, I don't see if you meant the uselessness of `sqrt` in Heron's variant. (it is the 2nd var (with inequality) doesn't deal with `sqrt` at all).

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy not only do you not _need_ to compute the square root, in fact it's wrong to do so! What _would_ be the root if the argument is negative? Certainly nothing you could then meaningfully compare with 0!

Comment: @leftaroundabout, In case of negative arguments I agree. But this is not awful, paying attention to the fact that triangle sides are >= 0. This function is for such simple cases, not for super complex math (or something alike). But I understood: seems the 2nd variant (without `sqrt`) is much more better.

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy, I don't know what you mean; you should listen carefully to leftaroundabout (always, and in particular here).

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy: “not for super complex math (or something alike)” – well, that's fine, and precisely the reason why you should not take the square root of a negative number! (It so happens that your original check _will work_, but more “out of luck” than anything else: `sqrt (-1)` results in the special IEEE745 value `NaN`, and whatever you compare with `NaN` always gives `False`. So... `sqrt (-1) > 0` is false, but `sqrt (-1) <= 0` is _also_ false, paradoxically.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout, now I see! Henceforth, I'll be careful with sqrt (and other cases).

Answer (score 2):

you need to convert the `Int` to a floating point number before calculating the square root and before dividing it with `/` (for integer division use `div` or `quot`).

Also one can simplify your `if ... then True else False`

```
isTriangle :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
isTriangle a b c = let a' = fromIntegral a
                       b' = fromIntegral b
                       c' = fromIntegral c
                       p = (a' + b' + c') / 2
                   in 0 < sqrt (p * (p - a') * (p - b') * (p - c'))
```